# get_nlcd error for some counties in some years

Tags: r, gis

I'm using `get_nlcd` in the `FedData` package to extract data for over 3,000 counties in the USA over several years. For most counties this works, but for many counties I am getting an error that looks like this:

```
Area of interest includes 2 NLCD tile(s).
(Down)Loading NLCD tile: N33W108
Downloading file (if necessary): https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/NLCD/data/2001/landcover/3x3/NLCD2001_LC_N33W108.zip
(Down)Loading NLCD tile: N36W108
Downloading file (if necessary): https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/NLCD/data/2001/landcover/3x3/NLCD2001_LC_N36W108.zip
Mosaicking NLCD tiles.
Error in v[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In matrix(ratvalues, nrow = length(ratvalues)/length(ratnames)) :
  data length [2303] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [255]
2: In matrix(ratvalues, nrow = length(ratvalues)/length(ratnames)) :
  data length [2303] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [255]
```

To provide some reproducible code, I'm providing a [link to a GIS layer](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3b69769aa9b646a483af81d05e7702d2), but you could probably produce the same error using any GIS layer from the USA that contains FIPS codes. In the reproducible code, I'll assume that you have unzipped the GIS layer and put it into your working directory.

```
library(sf)
library(FedData)

# read in shapefile: assuming you dowloaded the shapefile I provided, unzipped it, and put it in your working directory
shp <- read_sf("./USA_Counties_as_Shape/USA_Counties.shp") # using the shapefile that I linked to

# FIPS code for a county that doesn't work
which_fips <- "04001" # but if you set which_fips <- "04003", the function runs fine

# subset shapefile
sub_shp <- subset(shp, FIPS == which_fips)

# run function that is throwing error
nlcd_data <- get_nlcd(as(sub_shp, 'Spatial'), 
                      label = which_fips, 
                      year = 2001) # 2001 does not work in this county, but if you set year = 2006 for this county the function works fine
```

Am I doing something wrong with `get_nlcd`? Or is there a bug in the package or the data that is causing this error? I'd appreciate any advice you have.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was using `as(sub_shp, 'Spatial')` instead of just `sub_shp`. So the code works like this:

```
nlcd_data <- get_nlcd(sub_shp), 
                      label = which_fips, 
                      year = 2001)
```

This is discussed in more detail on [the FedData github issues page](https://github.com/ropensci/FedData/issues/46).